# the return values of deleting template object

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used to delete a template object by `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group.deleteObject` API.
If the transaction of delete is successful, this API has the return values, `DELETE_CLOUD_DISK_TEMPLATE` in `SoftLayer_Provisioning_Version1_Transaction_Status.name`.

But now this API doesn't return this value. So I can't determine the transaction is successful,or not.

Please let me know what I should check the return values if success.

Answer (score 0):

When a transaction has been completed successfuly the SoftLayer_Provisioning_Version1_Transaction_Status.name = COMPLETE, the status = DELETE_CLOUD_DISK_TEMPLATE does not mean that the transaction was successful, it may still fail.

The transactions can pass for several status names. I guess the reason you do not see the status name that you are looking for is due to the status name was not updated yet.

Normally the transaction status can be tracked calling the  getTransaction method of the object, but this is not possible using the deleteObject.

The best approach I found to know if your image template has been removed successfully is by fetching all your images template and review that the image, that you deleted, is not being listed anymore. To make the things easy you can use a filter to get only the deleted template when your result is empty is when the template has been deleted successfully.

e.g.

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectFilter={"privateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups": {"id": {"operation": 919351}}}

the request above will return the image template whose id is 919351
```

Regards